# Retrieve the local IP and port from an outbound Akka TCP stream

Tags: scala, networking, akka, akka-stream

I am dealing with a server for a rather picky protocol (SIP) that needs my local IP and port as part of the header structure. I am using an Akka TCP stream for its awesomeness but I am missing the equivalent of BSD socket's `getsockname` function. In Akka actor-oriented connections, the connection sends a convenient message reporting the local IP and port, but I cannot find a way to get this from the Akka Streams version. The stream is connected directly to some flow for further processing, but there is no room for a message containing the IP and port of the local side of the connection.

```
val connection = Tcp().outgoingConnection("www.google.com", 80)

val test = List("GET / HTTP/1.1", "Host: www.google.com", "\r\n").map(s ⇒ ByteString(s + "\r\n"))
val res = Source(test).via(connection).runFold(ByteString.empty)( _ ++ _ )

// How do I get the connection details here?
res.onComplete{
  case Success(resp) ⇒ println(resp.utf8String)
  case Failure(f) ⇒ println(f)
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I would start reading around next references: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/index-network.html possibly its just abstracted away etc

Comment: The data is bubbling just below the stream abstraction. I just don't see a "side channel" where the `Connect(remote, local)` can be delivered to or some exposed method to retrieve this information.

Comment: You haven't created the connection yet, just a stream which will, when materialized, create the connection. the address information is available in the materialized value, see: https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Tcp.html

Comment: Akka never fails to impress me. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the signature for the [`Tcp().outgoingConnection`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/Tcp.html#outgoingConnection(host:String,port:Int):akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[akka.util.ByteString,akka.util.ByteString,scala.concurrent.Future[akka.stream.scaladsl.Tcp.OutgoingConnection]]) method:

```
def outgoingConnection(host: String, port: Int):
  Flow[ByteString, ByteString, Future[OutgoingConnection]]
```

The materialized value is a `Future[OutgoingConnection]`, and the [`OutgoingConnection`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/Tcp$$OutgoingConnection.html) case class has a `localAddress` member.

To access the materialized value of the outgoing connection, and in turn the local address, use something like the following:

```
val (res1, res2) =
  Source(test)
    .viaMat(connection)(Keep.right)
    .toMat(Sink.fold(ByteString.empty)(_ ++ _))(Keep.both)
    .run()

res1 onComplete {
  case Success(OutgoingConnection(_, localAddr)) =>
    println(s"local address: ${localAddr}")
  case Failure(f) =>
    println(f)
}
```